# silverlight plug-in crashes in modal dialog

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, windows-7, crash, modal-dialog

In our system, a user first login to portal then can navigate to a page which hosts our embedded silverlight application [A]. There is one button in this SL app [A] which opens a browser modal dialog (not SL child window). This dialog will first sso authenticate user then redirect user to a page [B] which has another embedded silverlight app [C].

When this modal dialog is either about to load SL app C (just after redirect to page B but B is not rendered yet) or loading SL app C (page B is rendered, downloading SL xap file), user close this model dialog and repeat this show-then-close action. Silverlight plug-in will crash after a couple of times.

This issue only happens to Win7 32bit Google Chrome browser and happens to both SL4 and SL5. Does anyone have idea about this? Thanks a lot.